# How to add only embedded fields repetitively in mongodb using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Given the JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "Act_Name" : "prashanth",
    "Act_Alias" : "H C",
    "Group_Account_Name" : "Prashan",
    "OpeningBalance" : 10000,
    "Dr_Cr" : 10000,
    "Is_Reserved" : true,
    "Is_Group_Act" : false,
    "Contact_Name" : "Prashanth",
    "Contact_Address" : "Bangalore",
    "Cr_Limit" : 2000,
    "isDeleted" : true,
    "Cr_Days" : {
        "BillwiseTracking" : {
            "Reference_Number" : 123,
            "Reference_Date" : null,
            "Due_Date" : null,
            "Amount" : 12334,
            "Ref_Dr_Cr" : 12
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to repetitively add only the fields:

```
"Reference_Number" : 123,
"Reference_Date" : null,
"Due_Date" : null,
"Amount" : 12334,
"Ref_Dr_Cr" : 12
```

My code is follows.

```
BasicDBObject billwiseTracking = new BasicDBObject();
billwiseTracking.put("Reference_Number",referenceNumber);
billwiseTracking.put("Reference_Date", referenceDate);
billwiseTracking.put("Due_Date", dueDate);
billwiseTracking.put("Amount", amount);
billwiseTracking.put("Ref_Dr_Cr", refDrCr);

BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject("BillwiseTracking", billwiseTracking);

accountHeads.update(findQuery, new BasicDBObject("$set", updateObj));
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome. You forgot to explain what the problem is.

Comment: problem is every insertion extra document is creating.I want to add only embedding fields in a same document.

Comment: it is not well understandable que.

Comment: okay,1st time insertion i will add my all fields, after 1st insertion i want to add only embedding fields."Reference_Number" : 123,
"Reference_Date" : null,
"Due_Date" : null,
"Amount" : 12334,
"Ref_Dr_Cr" : 12 only these fields. my problem is extra document is creating in every insertion.

Comment: @user3756637 instead of explaining in the comments, just edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

i am not properly understand your Question  but if you want to append

**first**

**"BillwiseTracking" object under "Cr_Days"**
then  structure should like this

```
"Cr_Days" :
 {
        "BillwiseTracking" :
      [ 
        {
            "Reference_Number" : 123,
            "Reference_Date" : null,
            "Due_Date" : null,
            "Amount" : 12334,
            "Ref_Dr_Cr" : 12
        },
        {
            "Reference_Number" : 145,
            "Reference_Date" : null,
            "Due_Date" : null,
            "Amount" : 12355,
            "Ref_Dr_Cr" : 13
        }
    ]
  }
```

it means it should be array element and every time you have to append for **"BillwiseTracking"** value

this may be your Solution

```
   // query for append data ele.

        BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        updateQuery.put( "_id", 2 );

  // object to appen 

       BasicDBObject billwiseTracking = new BasicDBObject();
       billwiseTracking.put("Reference_Number",referenceNumber);
       billwiseTracking.put("Reference_Date", referenceDate);
       billwiseTracking.put("Due_Date", dueDate);
       billwiseTracking.put("Amount", amount);
       billwiseTracking.put("Ref_Dr_Cr", refDrCr);

// push used to append data elements
       BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject();
        updateCommand.put( "$push", new BasicDBObject( "BillwiseTracking", billwiseTracking ) );
// final query execution
        WriteResult result = shoppingLists.update( updateQuery, updateCommand, true, true );
```

Comment: Have u change your base document? and define "Cr_Days" as array in main 
document(database table). then try.. also please put log message.